# how to draw all routes in google map

Tags: java, javascript, android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I've made a application in android for tracking vehicles and visualizing the movement in web browser using JavaScript. the android app when moving inserts the new latitude and longitude into the database which on the other side is been used by the web application to show the online tracking.

somehow i did that for one vehicle .

but suppose there are five vehicles then how can we show all the five online tracking in Google-map

can anyone please tell me how to do this..

my code is given below

**map.jsp**

```
<html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <style type="text/css">
   body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
    #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
   </style>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png");
   var center = null;
   var map = null;
   var currentPopup;
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   var markLAT,markLNG;
   var marker;

function moveMarker( map, marker, lat, lon) {

    marker.setPosition( new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lon ) );
    map.panTo( new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lon ) );

};


  function addMarker(lat, lng, info)
 { 
   var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
   map.setCenter(pt);
   map.setZoom(17);
bounds.extend(pt);
marker = new google.maps.Marker(
{
    position: pt,
    icon: icon,
    map: map
});

var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
{
    content: "Driver: Manu",
    maxWidth: 300
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function()
{
    if (currentPopup != null)
    {
        currentPopup.close();
        currentPopup = null;
    }
    popup.open(map, marker);
    currentPopup = popup;
   });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function()
   {
    //map.panTo(center);
    //currentPopup = null;
   });
   }

function initMap()
{
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.013566, 76.331549),
zoom: 17,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
mapTypeControl: false,
mapTypeControlOptions:
{
   style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
},
navigationControl: true,
navigationControlOptions:
{
style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
 }
 });

routePoints = [];
  $.getJSON('Coordinates', function(items)
  {

   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      (function(item) {
          if(i==items.length-1)
        addMarker(item.lat, item.lng,  item.lng);
        markLAT=items[i].lat;
        markLNG=items[i].lng;
    })(items[i]);
    routePoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(items[i].lat,items[i].lng));
   }
   var route= new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: routePoints,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 2.0,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    editable: false
  });

  route.setMap(map);


  });

 center = bounds.getCenter();
 //map.fitBounds(bounds);

   }

 var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.getJSON('Updates', function(items)
  {

if(markLAT!=items[0].lat&&markLNG!=items[0].lng)
    {

    routePoints.push(new google.maps.LatLng(items[0].lat,items[0].lng));
    var route= new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: routePoints,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 2.0,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    editable: false
  });

  route.setMap(map);  
  //removeMarker(markLAT,markLNG);
  moveMarker(map,marker,items[0].lat,items[0].lng);
     markLAT=items[0].lat;
     markLNG=items[0].lng;        
    }
  });
//$('#load').load('index1.jsp').fadeIn("slow");
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

   </script>
   <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

    </head>
   <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
       <div id="load"> </div>
   <div id="map"></div>

    </html>
```

**Two Servlet classes  Coordinates.java, Updates.java**

**Coordinates.java**

```
package model;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Coordinates extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
             Connection connection;
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             String url="jdbc:mysql://144.76.19.105/iload?user=nidhish123&password=nidhish123";
             connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery("SELECT lat, lng from latng");
             ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();

             while(set.next())
             {
             Map<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
             options.put("lat", set.getString(1));
             options.put("lng", set.getString(2));
             ar.add(options);
             }
             String json = new Gson().toJson(ar); 
             response.setContentType("application/json");
             response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
             response.getWriter().write(json);
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Coordinates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Coordinates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Coordinates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Coordinates.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

**Updates.java**

```
package model;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class Updates extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
             ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();
             boolean foundResults = false;
             ResultSet set = null;
             Statement statement = null;         
             String lat=null;
             String lng=null;
                    int count=0;
                        try 
                        {
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://144.76.19.105/iload", "nidhish123", "nidhish123");
                            statement = conn.createStatement();
                            set = statement.executeQuery("SELECT lat,lng FROM latng ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
                            while(set.next())
                            {
                                Map<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
                                options.put("lat", set.getString(1));
                                options.put("lng", set.getString(2));
                                ar.add(options);
                            }
                            conn.close(); 
                            String json = new Gson().toJson(ar); 
                            response.setContentType("application/json");
                            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                            response.getWriter().write(json);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            out.print(e);
                        }
        }catch(Exception s){
            System.out.println("ERROR!!!");
            s.printStackTrace();
        }
         finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save each navigation path as [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=zh-cn#Polyline) , then render all of them in a loop by calling `Polyline.setVisible(true)`